# Python Enthought 32 vs. 64 bit version

Tags: python, scrapy, enthought

I want to execute the following command...

```
scrapy startproject resultScrapper
```

However, the following error shows up...

```
-bash: /Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/scrapy: /Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

which scrapy

```
/Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/scrapy
```

Here's $PATH

```
echo $PATH
/Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/bin:/Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin
```

I have deleted Canopy_32bit version...how is it still being referenced? $PATH does not contain a link to it either.

Comment: Did you restart your shell?

Comment: yes, I sourced ~/.bash_profile, as you can see changes to PATH above

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the interpreter is set incorrectly in the shebang line of the `scrapy` script.

If the output of

```
head -n1 /Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/scrapy
```

is

```
#! /Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python
```

then you should change it to either

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

(more portable, but it may not call the python you want)  or

```
#! /Users/usrname/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
```

(less portable, but forces the 64bit Enthought python; assuming that path is correct for your system)

More interesting is that a 64bit installation would link to the 32bit interpreter. There are a number of possible explanations, but the one I would worry about would be that there is some dependency that won't work on 64bit. For pure python (according to the website, Scrapy is), this shouldn't be a problem.